# Pyqt5 multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I have an app that creates mattes from image sequence running in the console it works as expected, but I want to change it to Pyqt5 UI for more comfort for setting the options and better look and feel.

When I connect all the UI elements to the functions that have to be used it works also fine just the main for loop that creates the mattes can take very long to processing all the images and the app is frozen in this time. So I wanted to make it multithreading so I have a progressbar and also the main for loop is running in background. I red many of stuff and watched many youtubes, but there are very simple examples with sleep and such stuff.

My project have three py files ui_main.py, window.py and modules.py.
In the window.py I import the ui_main and modules so it is the main file for execute.
The ui_main have a class inside the modules have just a bunch of def and variables inside.

My question is can I run the different tasks (main for loop and progressbar) simultaneously and how to achieve it?

here is the window.py

```
import ui_main
import modules


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()


class MainUIClass(QMainWindow, ui_main.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainUIClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.handel_buttons()
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        #self.threadclass.start()
        modules.ResolutionChecker(self.matteHeight_cbx.value())

    def _cancel(self):
        # super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.handel_buttons()

    def handel_buttons(self):
        self.imageRootDir_btn.clicked.connect(self.file_path)
        self.createMatte_btn.clicked.connect(self.cerate_matte)
        self.cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self._cancel)
        self.exit_btn.clicked.connect(modules.exitApp)
        self.matteHeight_cbx.valueChanged.connect(self.matte_hight)
        self.person_ckb.stateChanged.connect(modules.Person)
        self.vehicle_ckb.stateChanged.connect(modules.Vehicle)
        self.animal_ckb.stateChanged.connect(modules.Animal)
        self.hhThings_ckb.stateChanged.connect(modules.thing)

    def file_path(self):
        self.files = modules.FilePath(self)
        if self.files:
            print(str(self.files[0])) # Image Directory
            print(str(self.files[1])) # output directory
            print(str(self.files[2])) # image list

            self.imageDir_lne.setText(str(self.files[0]))
            self.createMatte_btn.setEnabled(True)
            self.cancel_btn.setEnabled(True)

    def matte_hight(self):
        #matteHight = self.matteHeight_cbx.value() #self.sp.value()
        modules.ResolutionChecker(self.matteHeight_cbx.value())

    def cerate_matte(self):
        #listOfFiles, outputDirectory, matteHeight
        #self.threadclass.start()

        print("send files to create matte")
        modules.Rotoscope(self.files[2], str(self.files[0]), str(self.files[1]), self.matteHeight_cbx.value())
        self.matte_name = modules.matte_name(self)
        print(self.matte_name)

    def run(self):
        self.threadclass.start(self.files, self.matteHeight_cbx.value())

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        print("send files to create matte")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainUIClass()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around. The GUI *is* the main loop and *must* run in the main thread, while the "workers" must be run in external threads. Also, all UI elements can only exist, be created and accessed from the main thread (including the progress bar) and can only be updated by the other threads through signals.

Comment: Also, just for understanding in my window.py is the class that display the GUI the buttons are connected to internal functions this calls the functions from the modules.py till hesre it works okay for setting the options. The image processing is also in the modules.py and it is called from the window.py also. Should I move this function from modules.py to window.py and call it there?